# Android multiple edittext with TextWatcher

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

i have three edittexts, and i a using Txtwatcher one each edittext, i am unable to get the following functionality
when i focus an enter value in ET1 ,based on the calculation ET2 ET3 will be updated, same if i chaged focus on the ET2 ,
 ET1 and ET3 will be updated.

Suppose when i entered value in ET1(ET2 and ET3 will be updated with value) ,now if  changed focus to ET2, 
 the ET2 should erase the value and should start enetering from first(also should erase  ET1 and ET3 value and replace with new value)

Iam doing as below but unable to get it work.

```
edt_hex_val.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {   
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String qtyString = s.toString().trim();
        if(qtyString.length() > 0 && edt_hex_val.isFocused()){
            edt_decimal_val.setText(String.valueOf(hextodecimal(qtyString)));
            edt_binary_val.setText(String.valueOf(hexToBin(qtyString)));
        }
        else if( edt_hex_val.isFocused()){
            edt_decimal_val.setText("");
            edt_binary_val.setText("");
        }

    }
});

edt_decimal_val.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {   
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String qtyString = s.toString().trim();
        if(qtyString.length() > 0 && edt_decimal_val.isFocused()){
            edt_hex_val.setText(String.valueOf(hextodecimal(qtyString)));
            edt_binary_val.setText(String.valueOf(hexToBin(qtyString)));
        }
        else  if( edt_decimal_val.isFocused()){
            edt_hex_val.setText("");
            edt_binary_val.setText("");
        }

    }
});

edt_binary_val.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {   
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String qtyString = s.toString().trim();
        if(qtyString.length() > 0 && edt_binary_val.isFocused()){
            edt_decimal_val.setText(String.valueOf(hextodecimal(qtyString)));
            edt_hex_val.setText(String.valueOf(hexToBin(qtyString)));
        }
        else  if( edt_binary_val.isFocused()) {
            edt_hex_val.setText("");
            edt_binary_val.setText("");
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one..**

```
edt_hex_val.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {   
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String qtyString = s.toString().trim();
        if(qtyString.length() > 0){
            edt_decimal_val.setText(String.valueOf(hextodecimal(qtyString)));
            edt_binary_val.setText(String.valueOf(hexToBin(qtyString)));
        }
        else{
            edt_decimal_val.setText("");
            edt_binary_val.setText("");
        }

    }
});

edt_decimal_val.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {   
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String qtyString = s.toString().trim();
        if(qtyString.length() > 0){
            edt_hex_val.setText(String.valueOf(hextodecimal(qtyString)));
            edt_binary_val.setText(String.valueOf(hexToBin(qtyString)));
        }
        else{
            edt_hex_val.setText("");
            edt_binary_val.setText("");
        }

    }
});

edt_binary_val.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {   
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String qtyString = s.toString().trim();
        if(qtyString.length() > 0){
            edt_decimal_val.setText(String.valueOf(hextodecimal(qtyString)));
            edt_hex_val.setText(String.valueOf(hexToBin(qtyString)));
        }
        else{
            edt_hex_val.setText("");
            edt_binary_val.setText("");
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit like this to solve stack overflow error.

```
edt_binary_val.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
{
    boolean editing = false;
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {   
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    String qtyString = s.toString().trim();

    if(!editing) 
    {
    editing = true;
    if(qtyString.length() > 0){
        edt_decimal_val.setText(String.valueOf(hextodecimal(qtyString)));
        edt_hex_val.setText(String.valueOf(hexToBin(qtyString)));
    }
    else{
        edt_hex_val.setText("");
        edt_binary_val.setText("");
    }

    editing = false;
   }


}
});
```